# Embedding HTML into an email via MAPI32

Tags: c#

I have a program in C# that has a call:

```
myEmail.SendMailPopup("Hi", "This is my email body");
```

which uses MAPI32.DLL to open an Outlook email with the subject of Hi and a body of This is my email body.

However, when I send it HTML, such as

```
myEmail.SendMailPopup("Hi", "<html><body><b>Bold text</b></body></html>");
```

the message body contains what it literally in the quotation marks.

Is there a way to parse this HTML to show "Bold text" in bold?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I'm not sure that is possible](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268440).  You might want to check out the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem.aspx) option.  Just found a good [example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310262).

Comment: @drachenstern - Youre not crazy :)

Comment: I'm at least hoping that since he has a wrapper (sendmailpopup) that the wrapper might, ya know, hook into an actually different library than MAPI32.dll ... doubtful, I know.

Comment: No, it is MAPI32.dll that is being used when the actual message is sent. The ShowPopupMessage just createst the MapiMessage and then makes the call to MAPISendMail.  I was hoping that the "messageType" field could be used to set it to HTML or something similar, as I cannot find out much about the messageType field of a MapiMessage.

Comment: @John - Yeah I dont think you can set that messageType, its just not supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673519/send-email-in-html-format

Comment: If I were to investigate using another DLL, where would you suggest starting?  I want to keep it as broad a scope as MAPI would provided, not limiting myself to just Outlook.

Comment: @John - I would take a look at the SmtpClient: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Comment: Indeed, SmtpClient was designed for just such a thing, yes? Or ... if @John needs it to work to show the message in Outlook before it being sent, then I think that he has to target Outlook. @John, it sounds like it's time to redefine the question, so mark this as the answer and start a new one, this time explaining the premise and the desired effect/outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Since `SendMailPopup` is not a `MAPI32.dll` method that I'm aware of, is there anyway to share the internals of what `SendMailPopup` does? Does it by chance encode the message in anyway?

Doesn't `MAPI32.DLL` assume

```
[DllImport("MAPI32.DLL")]
static extern int MAPISendMail(IntPtr sess, IntPtr hwnd, MapiMessage message, int flg, int rsv);
```