# C# - Send HTML email with line breaks

Tags: c#, email

I'm attempting to send emails from my C# app using the System.Net.Mail.MailMessage class. For the body of the email, I want to include line breaks to create separate blocks of text. How can I get an email client, like Outlook, to respect the line breaks when display the email has HTML to users? What character(s) do I insert in the body of the email text so that the line breaks are treated as line breaks?

Note: The body of my email is pure text, not HTML.

Comment: For best results, show your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send Email in HTML Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673519/send-email-in-html-format)

Comment: It would help if you explain what you mean by "line breaks" and "blocks of text". In my mind those are different things.

Comment: @Dour - 'Blocks of text' was a poor choice of words. I simply want to embed a new line command in the text of the email. BTW, the text of the email is not HTML. It is pure text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) property.  That will insert a newline string defined for the current environment.

Answer (score 14):

Line breaks are white space characters, and all white space characters are interpreted as spaces in HTML.

You can use break tags (`<br/>`) to add line breaks in the HTML code, and you can use paragraph tags (`<p>...</p>`) around paragraphs to get a distance between them.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear. I am sending regular text in the body of my email, not HTML. So simply embedding <br/> in the text of the body doesn't cause the email client (Outlook) to issue line breaks.

Comment: @Hosea146: I see, the HTML that you meantion in the question is actually not HTML but text that represents HTML code... If it's a plain text mail then you use `Environment.NewLine` to add line breaks (just as usual).

Answer (score 7):

You need to insert HTML line-breaks i.e. `<br/>`

Comment: I probably wasn't clear. I am sending regular text in the body of my email, not HTML. So simply embedding <br/> in the text of the body doesn't cause the email client (Outlook) to issue line breaks.

Answer (score 4):

using the parograph tag is the best way in my opinion because it keeps the format clean and easy to maintain.

I hope this helps.

```
<p>Dear Mike</p>
<p>This is a sample message</p>
<p><b>Thank You,</b></p>
```

Comment: If you look at previous entries from 4 years ago, other folks suggested <br> tags, and the OP pointed out that this wasn't the issue, and so paragraph tags (note spelling) wouldn't help either.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't go over all the comments. Thank You for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send the email as HTML, use the break tag as others have described. If you want line breaks to work, you'll need to send the message as plain text, which can be specified by setting [IsBodyHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx) = false.

If your existing line breaks aren't being used, try forcing with "\n" which is an escape sequence for a new line.

Answer (score 0):

```
email.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.Text, stringThatCointainsMessage);
```

at least using `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data` this will solve the problem

you need to use the overloaded method and the enum `BodyType.Text`