# Cannot send an email with ICS (THtmlSmtpCli) from a Thread in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, email

We have been using [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html), `THtmlSmtpCli` to send emails from our applications for some time now, both in the Main VCL thread and Threads. Earlier this week we discovered that it we are no longer able to send email from Threads. Sending it from the main VCL thread works fine.

So, I my question is two-fold:

1. Has anybody experienced the same problem?
2. Are there any other components that we could look at to send emails from Delphi Apps.

The code we use is as follows ...

```
FRunning := True;
FHtmlSmtpClient := THtmlSmtpCli.Create(nil);
with FHtmlSmtpClient do
  begin
    Port := '25';
    Host := FHost;
    AuthType := smtpAuthNone;
    ConfirmReceipt := FReadReceipt;
    HdrPriority := smtpPriorityNone;
    ContentType := smtpHtml;
    FromName := FFromAddr;
    HdrFrom := FFromAddr;
    HdrTo := FToAddr;
    HdrSubject := FSubject;

    OnCommand := FHtmlSmtpClientCommand;
    OnRequestDone := FHtmlSmtpClientRequestDone;
    OnSessionClosed := FHtmlSmtpClientSessionClosed;

    { Start first operation to do to send an email          }
    { Next operations are started from OnRequestDone event  }
    Connect;
  end;

//Process the requests to send the email
procedure FHtmlSmtpClientRequestDone(Sender: TObject; RqType: TSmtpRequest; ErrorCode:     word);
begin
  if not FRunning then
    Exit;

  { Start next operation, but first check if previous one was OK }
  if ErrorCode <> 0 then
    begin
      FRunning := FALSE;   { Terminate All-In-One demo }
      Exit;
    end;

  case RqType of
    smtpConnect:
      begin
        if FHtmlSmtpClient.AuthType = smtpAuthNone then
          FHtmlSmtpClient.Helo
        else
          FHtmlSmtpClient.Ehlo;
      end;

    smtpHelo: FHtmlSmtpClient.MailFrom;
    smtpEhlo: FHtmlSmtpClient.Auth;
    smtpAuth: FHtmlSmtpClient.MailFrom;
    smtpMailFrom: FHtmlSmtpClient.RcptTo;
    smtpRcptTo: FHtmlSmtpClient.Data;
    smtpData: FHtmlSmtpClient.Quit;
    smtpQuit: FRunning := FALSE;
  end;
end;
```

Regards, Pieter.

Comment: OK, so where does it get stuck?   Does it fail to resolve the server, fail to connect, faile to authorize, fail to send, fail to close?  You have the code there - we cannot magically tell what is wrong!

Comment: I use Synapse http://ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php without any problems. Although I have never tried to send emails from different threads. But I assume it should be no problem with Synapse as they are basic objects (not TComponent descendants) and you don't need to catch any events if you don't want to.

Comment: I suspect a message pump is needed.

Comment: Synapse may well experience th same issue, (whatever that is:).  The Indy mail component is being instantiated in the thread, (FHtmlSmtpClient := THtmlSmtpCli.Create(nil);), and is not plonked on some form.  This must have to do with something 'Earlier this week'.

Comment: Oh - please forgive me - I misread the original mail.  ICS, not Indy!  @mj2008 may well be right.  Nevertheless, if the code worked last week, then the thread must have been running a message loop last week & so we're back to 'what has changed?'. Has someone added some VCL property set/method call that they should not have?

Comment: The server name is resolved and the state changed to wsConnecting. It looks like the threaded version does not get the answer back from the server to indicate that the connection was successful. With regards to 'earlier this week...', we've installed a new MS Exchange Server and de-comissioned the old server. I've compare the ICS source with the original and that is still identical.

Comment: 'installed a new MS Exchange Server' - I would be 99.999% sure where the problem is, if it wasn't for the fact that you can send mails from the main thread.  Are you sure that the authentication information is correctly signaled to, (or read by), the thread?  Is here some new character or other characteristic in the authentication for the new server that might cause a problem with thread comms?  Any Unicode issues with the authentication strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your second question, you can use Indy, which ships with Delphi. It has `TIdMessage` and `TIdSMTP` components, and a `TIdMessageBuilderHtml` utility class.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I found a link to a blog post that you made. Our emails now work perfectly well.  http://www.projectindy.org/Sockets/Blogs/RLebeau/2005_08_17_A.EN.aspx The Original post by http://stackoverflow.com/users/11480/tondrej is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673519/send-email-in-html-format